# filter pandas dataframe by function on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a Date used as index, I would like to extract all rows that are for a given month say January. Eg given

```
Date         Col1 
2000-01-01    1   
...
2000-12-31    12   
2001-01-01    1   
...
2001-12-31    12   
2002-01-01    1   
...
2002-12-31    12
```

then this works

```
f = df.index.map(lambda x: x.month==1)
new_df = df[f]
```

Is there a simpler way of getting new_df?

I would have expected to be able to do something like `df.loc[lambda x: x.month==1]` but this does not work because `x` is actually `df` (which is counter-intuitive as `.loc` expect actual labels in all other forms of `.loc` calls so I would have though `x` would be each label of the index). Or  `df.filter(lambda x: x.month==1)` but `filter` does not accept a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) with `loc` to return index where condition matches

```
df.loc[df.index.month==1]
#df[df.index.month==1]
```

---

```
            Col1
Date            
2000-01-01   1.0
2001-01-01   1.0
2002-01-01   1.0
```